# Quickly Updating a Bit Field for Added Permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a Ruby on Rails application that is using bit fields to store user settings. I'm now adding additional bits that must have the default set based on the users existing permissions. For example, if a user has permission 'A' or 'B', they automatically get permission 'C'. Does any good way exist of doing this through an UPDATE ALL query?

Comment: Can you add model /schema information so we have some context to help you with?

Comment: This smells like a business rule to me -- which would imply that the logic should go in the model.  Of course, you will need a one-time update to go in the migration, too, which I think is what you are asking about.  As Jeff says, we'd need to know more about your schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight SQL in your migration is probably your best bet:

```
def self.up
    execute(%Q{
        UPDATE table
        SET permissions = permissions | bit_C
        WHERE permissions & bits_A_and_B <> 0
    })
end
```

Replace `bit_C` with the appropriate bitmap that just has the bit for permission C set and `bits_A_and_B` with the bitmap that just has the bits for permissions A and B set (both of them). The [bit operators for PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE) are pretty much the same (except bitwise XOR) as they are in C. Similar things will work if you're using [bitstrings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-bitstring.html#FUNCTIONS-BIT-STRING-OP-TABLE) instead of integers for your bitmaps.